# how i disable the line showing in the code?

Tags: themes, vscode-extensions

there is a line show for all block
[this line showing in the code that i want to hide it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Jm1.png) 
is a litter bit annoying when i work in vs ,i think this is an extension that is enabled but i check for all extensions and i try a lot but i cannot.